# Splitting n similar objects into k different groups with each group having a unique amount of objects

Tags: combinatorics

Title sums it up. This restriction seems more tricky than the ones where there is a requirement on the amount in each box separately.

if helpful, this can also be written as:
unique solutions to x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 = k, such that all of the variables are different and non-negative whole numbers.

Comment: Were you thinking of using stars and bars with constraints to solve this ? Or else, what have you tried so far ? Please edit in your efforts, your line of thinking.

Comment: If the number of similar objects is $n,$ I would think your example was the case of $k=5$ different groups, so I'd have expected $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=n$ where you want $x_j \neq x_k$ for all $j \neq k.$ [I think it goes against your verbal description to use k as the sum result.]

Comment: @coffeemath, agree with you, I will even say $x_i \ne x_j$ for all $i \ne j$ , because $k$ is already used in the definition of the problem.  I think that when we write $n=ak+b$, if $b=0$ ($n$ is a multiple of $k$), it will impact significantly the result.

Comment: @dumda It seems hard to find a closed formula to generalize this problem for $n,k$. One way you might think to use is apply inclusion-exclusion principle to eliminate k-repeated $\cup$ (k-1)-repeated $\cup$ ... $\cup$ 2-repeated, which also dependends on how many ways your n can be divided by that a $k$. I hope someone could bring a better approach.

Comment: Your problem has been studied. Topic is compositions of n into k distinct parts. The following has a short table and some known results. [ not quite your problem as they do not allow a part to be zero.] [https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Compositions-of-n-with-m-distinct-parts-Fn-m-1-n-16_tbl1_220620848

Comment: @Lourrran The use of indices same as another letter used in a problem is not likely to cause confusion. I don't know why you mention n=ak+b...